# Post to Twitter using C# without logging in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to tweet on behalf of a single Twitter account.

There is a lot of conflicting and outdated info on this.

Do I really need OAuth, or can I generate the token manually then save the token in my app to post to the account permanently?

Does this token expire?

Comment: `Do I really need OAuth` Yes.

Comment: `There is a lot of conflicting and outdated info on this.` - Twitter's documentation should be perfectly update to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Twitter documentation you should use 3-legged OAuth (see "Want to read or post Twitter data on behalf of visitors to your website..." [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens)). And if you read about [3-legged OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization) you will find that it uses the [endpoint GET /oauth/authorize](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authorize), for which the documentation states it uses OAuth 1.0 flow. And in [this section of the FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#7188) it says the following:

> The access tokens yielded to your through the OAuth process do not
>   have an explicit expiration datetime attached to them. They will be
>   valid for use when making requests on behalf of your users for as long
>   as the user has granted your application access. A user can revoke
>   access to your application at any time.
>
> Please note that the strings representing access tokens are not static
>   -- if a user revokes your application or otherwise transits from one permission level to another (such as from read-only to read-write),
>   the strings will be altered.

So from this I would derive that yes, you can get the token manually and then use that as long as you do not revoke the app or change the permission level, but I would probably not recommend it. Maybe if you dont want to implement OAuth you could check out one of the [.NET libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) available for the Twitter API and hope someone else has already done what you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom